# Error - Variable type "X" is an abstract class - c++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract

I was trying to find the solution to my problem, but I don´t progress in any way, so I need you to help with this.

my abstract class is:

```
class Expression
{
public:
    Expression();
    virtual ~Expression();
    virtual double evaluate() const = 0; // calculates and returns the value of expression
    virtual void print() const = 0; // prints the mathematical expression as string
};
```

my Subclass:

```
class Const : public Expression
{
public:
    Const(double valIn);

    double evaluate();

    void print() const;

private:
    double val;
};
```

and the line I am having problems with is:

```
Const c(4);
```

from the function:

```
void testConst()
{
    Const c(4);
    c.print();
    std::cout << " = " << c.evaluate() << std::endl;
}
```

If I should post some more information, I will gladly edit the text. Thank you in advance

Comment: `Const :: evaluate` is not const - so the signatures do not match. 

Use `override` in modern C++

Answer (score 3):

`Const::evaluate()` has a different signature than `Expression::evaluate() const`. Change your second expression to be const, then it works.

With C++11 there is the new `override` keyword, where the compiler gives you a better error message, if you have no matching signature in the parent class. 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override